# Is it okay to repeat "to" in a string of verbs?

Tags: verbs, conjunction-reduction

Is it okay to repeat the word "to" in a string of verbs? See the following sentence. Does repeating "to" serve an important function or should it be deleted?

> Throughout history, humans have tinkered with the world around them in an effort to learn, to discover, to wonder, and to invent.

Comment: In some cases, especially spoken, you might want to include "to" so that you can emphasize each verb in the sentence, but otherwise it shouldn't matter. "In an effort to learn, discover, wonder, and invent" carries the same meaning as "in an effort to learn, to discover, to wonder, and to invent" to me, save any need to emphasize the verb as you might in a speech.

Answer (score 1):

It's very much "ok"; it's somewhat unnecessary; and in some cases it’s the right thing to do for non-“grammatical” reasons.

@Dispenser’s comment partly covers this. In narrating a television programme, for example (I’m guessing this might be the context), repeating the *to* creates a rhythm to the line that simply isn’t there if you omit them. It’s (a little) similar to [*assonance*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assonance).